# How to redirect a webpage using an array of urls in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

What if I have an array with URLS that I want my webpage to redirect to, how can I loop into that array forever, unless I close the browser?

Let’s say I have

```
var urls = ['/news/1', 'news/2', 'news/3', '/update/1', '/news4', 'news/5', 'news/6', 'update/2'] etc….
```

I have a single HTML template that only changes the content of the elements inside based my database records. I want to redirect my page (same HTML template) to the following urls every 10 minutes.

I have:

```
<script>
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location=‘/news/1'
    }, 10000);

     // This will only redirect once to news/1 after 10seconds. 

</script>
```

How can I do a proper loop here on my url array?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: The page is going to reload each time you do this, so all you need to do is figure out the index in your array for the current page, then find the next one (looping back to index 0 if at the end).

Comment: so instead of hardcoding the windows.location, I need create a loop of indices?

Comment: Do you really want to reload the entire page each time, or are you looking for something like a carousel feature that will rotate content on a specific portion of the page?  If you want to reload the page each time, then you would need to check if each item in `urls` matches the end of the current `window.location` and, if so, go to the next one instead of hard-coding `news/1`

Answer (score 2):

You can check on which url you currently are, update the index, and start your timeout. Put this in every page:

```
var urls = ['/news/1', '/news/2', '/news/3', '/update/1', '/news4', '/news/5', '/news/6', '/update/2'],
    currentPath = window.location.pathname,
    currentIndex = urls.findIndex(function(url){
        return currentPath == url;
    });

if(currentIndex < urls.length - 1){
    currentIndex++;
} else {
    currentIndex = 0;
}

setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.pathname = urls[currentIndex];
}, 10000);
```

> **Note:** Here, I used `window.location.pathname`, which is the part of the URL right after your domain name. For this to work, you need to only have absolute paths with a slash at the beginning. You could also use full URLs, but in this case, use `window.location.href` instead of `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: Woah. Thank you very much!

Comment: What happens, if the "update" url is a different HTML page? That means I will break into the loop because I will load another html and js file as I go to update/1? Is there a way to keep this logic run in 2-3 of my html pages?

Comment: @Marvin I don't really understand what you mean, could you elaborate? This snippet of code will infinitely loop through a specific set of URLs (if they all exist and call this JS script). What else are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im thinking of separating one or two html pages. All urls with 'news' will have one html template. All 'updates' url will have their own html template and js file. If I do this, the logic to redirect to the url array will break.

Comment: @Marvin Sorry, but I still don't see your problem. Why would it break? The HTML templates don't have any effect on this script. You just need to make sure that each url in the list goes to a page that calls this script

Comment: hi Blex, I will give it a shot and will update you if it does work! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have the same script running on all the pages from your list
2. You need to have the same array of addresses on all the pages from your list
3. On each redirect add the index of the next link to redirect as a hash to the link the page is being redirected ex: `/news/1#2`
4. The index of the link you need to redirect at each iteration you can get through `document.location.hash`